# Calculate distance Between Bluetooth device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to calculate distance Bluetooth Paired device from android mobile. I am new in Android Bluetooth Concept can any one suggest me it's possible or not possible in android sdk.if it's possible post any code or tutorial link!

Comment: Is there any way of getting a time stamp of the data packet leaving the one bluetooth device and comparing it to the timestamp on the receiving end, then using that as the duration of travel and then multiply that by the speed of radio waves to get the distance? I suppose this would assume line of sight and the signal has not bounce off a wall or something but maybe could work if the timing was in sync somehow?

Answer (score 8):

The [Bluetooth signal strength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_RSSI) distance relation depends on the devices (built-in Bluetooth device, antenna, actual orientation of device), current way the persons hold their devices, objects in-between... You could measure this for a pair of devices for a given situation and use these information.

A larger and more general solution would incorporate an external Bluetooth network. [Bluetooth triangulation](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa06/cse237a/finalproj/almula.pdf) is the basic concept, that will help. The link will give an insight on certainties that are achievable with such a setup. Take is as an upper limit, a device to device approach will be worse.

Answer (score 4):

The EE Stack Exchange site has a [more complete answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/310370/116328) which includes a mention of Apple using 802.11v for determining if Apple Watch is close to a MacBook.

> Bluetooth uses radio, and radio travels at the speed of light. A 1cm round trip will take less than 100ps. Timing something that short will be tricky, probably you'll want a 10GHz clock, though there are other options. But even then, Bluetooth isn't designed to instantly echo the radio message. If you receive, process and re-transmit the message, then the processing delay will be much longer than the time of flight, and will vary randomly by at least the period of the clock used with the Bluetooth chip.

Comment: Hi, this is super interesting. But theoretically speaking it's possible build an app that can tell whether you're getting closer to the paired device, right? Sort of a cold/warm kind of game? Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Maybe, you can get approximate value from signal indicator but it's too much subject because of envirounment - is there something between connected devices, some reflection surfaces, etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way you can research, is coding a response time.  just calculate the bluethooth response time in nano secs, physically measure the distance between the devices and make a tree rule... is the same concept of GPS.  This is a Laboratory work.  I have a project that i have to develop it, in schedule i will taking it in a month.

Comment: i'm trying to do same thing ,,but the anano second error rate is high in a mobile device not like atomic clock ,,did you  try this ,,  and how much error in the end result distance

Answer (score 0):

OFC, its possible. It just requires ultra precise app, build to calculate "pings" between the two objects - kinda like ekko-location or laser distance measurement - its about how much time a specific signal travels back and forth.