# Is it possible to detect nearest Bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hello I am building an app in Android and I need to scan for Bluetooth devices and only show the nearest one. I looked into android's bt API and this page http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-bluetooth-scanner-with-androids-bluetooth-api--cms-24084.
But i still can't find a solution is this even possible?

An example of this is me standing and 2 more persons standing next to me one 1 meter from me and the other 2 meters from me, both with their phone and Bluetooth on. I need to detect only the person 1 meter from me. To clarify i need to filter the nearest device from the pool of devices bluetooth search returns me, not to calculate a distance between paired devices.
Any help i would be grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance Between Bluetooth device in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846506/calculate-distance-between-bluetooth-device-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's not possible on Android, at least not with just Bluetooth. You could look at the signal strength for each device, but it's possible for the signal strength to be stronger for a far away object than for a close one.